# rreHardcopyPrintPDF popover disappears below the horizon

Tags: ios, ipad, pdf, livecode

I'm having a problem with rreHardcopyPrintPDF when I try to print a PDF I've just created.  I suspect that the rreHardcopyPrintPDF popover disappears below the visible card boundaries.  I've checked the rect of the current card and it's 0,0,2048,1536.  The card (iPad) is in landscape mode so if I'm reading the Livecode dictionary correctly the rect is actually portrait.  There is method in this madness as there is a hidden card which is indeed portrait that holds the layout of the PDF I want to print (A4 layout).  This works fine when the PDF gets generated.
This is the code:

```
if rreHardcopyIsAvailable() then
      put the rectangle of card "AdminReportPrint" into tSaveRect
      answer "Report Print " & tSaveRect
      put the rectangle of card "AdminReport2" into tSaveRect1
      answer "Report 2 " & tSaveRect1
      set the rectangle of this card to 0,0,1536,2048
      put the rectangle of this card into tSaveRectx
      answer "This Card " & tSaveRectx
      rreHardcopyPrintPDF tPDFPath, "Printing the Report"
      if the result = "" then
         answer "OK"
      else
         answer the result
      end if
      set the rectangle of this card to 0,0,2048,1536
   end if
```

If I run the code without the 'Answer' dialogue I get a screen and when I tap I get "printing cancelled" which is expected since I tapped outside the popover.  If I run it with the answer dialogue it stops at the first 'set rect' line. I've also tried `set the height of this card to 1536`

Can anyone shed some light?  I know rreHardcopyPrintPDF uses the rect of the card to determine the position of the popover.  So is there another way to change the location of the popover?

TIA, AA.

Answer (score 0):

rreHardcopyPrintPDF will present the popover from the rect of the target. Are you by any chance sending a message to the card or stack to do your print job?

You can override this behavior by adding the optional rect third parameter:

```
rreHardcopyPrintPDF tPDFPath, "Printing the Report", the rect of btn "print"
```

Comment: Monte, I hope you're a drinker because I owe you a beer! THANK YOU!